# Pandas Yahoo Stock API

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am new to Pandas (and Python) and trying to working with the Yahoo API for stock prices.

I need to get the data, loop through it and grab the dates and values.

here is the code

```
df = pd.get_data_yahoo( symbols = 'AAPL',
     start = datetime( 2011, 1, 1 ),
     end = datetime( 2012, 1, 1 ),
     interval = 'm' )
```

results are:

```
df
            Open        High         Low       Close     Volume
Date                                                                    
2011-01-03  325.640015  348.600006  324.840027  339.320007  140234700   
2011-02-01  341.299988  364.899994  337.720001  353.210022  127618700   
2011-03-01  355.470001  361.669983  326.259979  348.510010  125874700
```

I can get the dates but not the month date value because it is the index(?)

How best to loop through the data for this information?  This is about processing the data and not sorting or searching it.

Comment: `df = df.assign(month=df.index.month)`

Comment: Show us what you're wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over the rows in your dataframe, and do some processing, then `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` works great.

**Code:**

Some mock processing code...

```
def process_data(row):
    # the index becomes the name when converted to a series (row)
    print(row.name.month, row.Close)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data

df = data.get_data_yahoo(
    'AAPL',
    start=dt.datetime(2011, 1, 1),
    end=dt.datetime(2011, 5, 1),
    interval='m')
print(df)

# process each row
df.apply(process_data, axis=1)
```

**Results:**

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date                                                                    
2011-01-03  325.640015  348.600006  324.840027  339.320007  140234700   
2011-02-01  341.299988  364.899994  337.720001  353.210022  127618700   
2011-03-01  355.470001  361.669983  326.259979  348.510010  125874700   
2011-04-01  351.110016  355.130005  320.160004  350.130005  128252100   

            Adj Close  
Date                   
2011-01-03  43.962147  
2011-02-01  45.761730  
2011-03-01  45.152802  
2011-04-01  45.362682  

1 339.320007
2 353.210022
3 348.51001
4 350.130005
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what made my life groovy when trying to work with the data from Yahoo.
First was getting the date from the dataframe index.

```
df = df.assign( date = df.index.date )
```

here are a few others I found helpful from dealing with the data.

```
df [ 'diff' ] = df [ 'Close' ].diff( )
df [ 'pct_chg' ] = df [ 'Close' ].pct_change()
df [ 'hl' ] = df [ 'High' ] - df [ 'Low' ]
```

Pandas is amazing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime    

start = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 27)
df = web.DataReader("GOOGL", 'yahoo', start, end)

dates =[]
for x in range(len(df)):
    newdate = str(df.index[x])
    newdate = newdate[0:10]
    dates.append(newdate)

df['dates'] = dates

print df.head()
print df.tail()
```

Also, take a look at the link below for more helpful hints of how to do these kinds of things.

https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from datetime import date
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() 
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


# Tickers List
tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL','FB', 'WB' , 'MO']

today = date.today()

# We can get data by our choice by giving days bracket
start_date= "2010-01-01"


files=[]
def getData(ticker):
    print (ticker)
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=today)
    dataname= ticker+'_'+str(today)
    files.append(dataname)
    SaveData(data, dataname)

# Create an data folder to save these data file in data folder.
def SaveData(df, filename):
    df.to_csv('./data/'+filename+'.csv')


for tik in tickers_list:
    getData(tik)
```

Comment: I gave up on yahoo a long time ago and went with EOD.   https://eodhistoricaldata.com